# How do you rollback to the next iteration in a loop?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, exception, plsql

To explain my question easier I will just paste my whole code:

```
drop table tst;

create table tst
(t1 number(2));

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
  TYPE vltp IS TABLE OF NUMBER(3);
  vl vltp := vltp(2,12,33,344,55,66,7,555,4);
  NUMBER_TO_BIG EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(NUMBER_TO_BIG, -01438);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN vl.FIRST .. vl.LAST LOOP
    INSERT INTO tst VALUES (vl(i));
    SAVEPOINT ONE;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NUMBER_TO_BIG THEN
    ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT ONE;
END;
/

select * from tst;
```

Basically, when I am inserting 344 into the table I get an exception (NUMBER_TO_BIG) and I want it to roll back to the loop but skip that number.

The expected output:

```
tst
-----
2
12
33
55
66
7
4
```

Actual output:

```
no rows selected
```

It is rolling back all the changes, not just that one number.

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be much more simple and efficient to use SQL for the insert, and a LOG ERRORS clause to handle the rejected rows: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9014.htm#BGBDIGAH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hello i have illustrtaed a small snippet to replicate your scenario. Let me know if this helps.

--Check for existing table with same name and dropping if already exists
DROP TABLE tst;


--Create Table
CREATE TABLE tst
  (t1 NUMBER(2)
  );


--Anonymous block to perform the task 
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
TYPE vltp
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER
  (
    3
  )
  ;
  vl vltp := vltp(2,12,33,344,55,66,7,555,4);
  NUMBER_TO_BIG EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(NUMBER_TO_BIG, -01438);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN vl.FIRST .. vl.LAST
  LOOP
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tst VALUES
      (vl(i)
      );
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN NUMBER_TO_BIG THEN
  NULL;
  dbms_output.put_line('skipping the value');
  END;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Comment: So from my understanding, in my code when it reaches the exception, it goes down the code until it finds how to handle it. In yours when it reaches the exception, because it is in the loop, it treats it as sort of an 'if' statement. So it reaches an exception, says: if exception do nothing. Or am i thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: Yupps your understanding is correct. Since exception handling is there in the loop itself, it will skip the exceptioned value and continue the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should handle the exception inside the loop itself. It will continue with the loop, once the exception is handled.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  TYPE vltp IS TABLE OF NUMBER(3);
  vl vltp := vltp(2,12,33,344,55,66,7,555,4);

  NUMBER_TO_BIG EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(NUMBER_TO_BIG, -01438);

BEGIN
  FOR i IN vl.FIRST .. vl.LAST LOOP
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tst VALUES (vl(i));
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NUMBER_TO_BIG THEN
        NULL;
    END;

    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


SQL> SELECT * FROM tst;

        T1
----------
         2
        12
        33
        55
        66
         7
         4

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: There is no reason to include `exception when others...` in this sample.. Whatever tool you are using will get you the error information by default.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this...

```
drop table tst;
--create table
create table tst
(t1 number(2));

--start of code
DECLARE
  TYPE vltp IS TABLE OF NUMBER(3);
  vl vltp := vltp(2, 12, 33, 344, 55, 66, 7, 555, 4);
  NUMBER_TO_BIG EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(NUMBER_TO_BIG, -01438);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN vl.FIRST .. vl.LAST LOOP
    begin
      INSERT INTO tst VALUES (vl(i));
    exception
      when NUMBER_TO_BIG then
         --log exeption into log table here
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    end;
  END LOOP;
  commit;
exception
  when others then
    --log exeption into log table here
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
```